# Groups $G$ of order $8$ so that $U(\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z})\cong G$ for some $n$.

Tags: group-theory, number-theory

I cant solve this exercise.

Find all groups $G$ of order $8$ so that $U(\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z})\cong G$ for some $n$.

I need a little help here. thanks!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hints**

First, we know the group is abelian, and there are only a few abelian groups of order $8$.  How many?

Second, the order of $U(\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z})$ is equal to $\varphi(n)$, [Euler's totient function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_totient_function).  There are only finitely many numbers $n$ for which $\varphi(n)=8$ ($5$ I believe), and they aren't too hard to find.  You could just do a brute force calculation of $U(\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z})$ for all such values.  I can't think of another way to do this.

Comment: I need to know if I am right. There are 3 abelian gruops of order $8$. Then my answer to the problem have to be $3$ or less gruops, right? I friend told me that the number of grups are $5$,I think him is counting the non abelian groups

Comment: yes, I was right... your help was very useful!

Comment: Yes, there are only 3 abelian groups of order 8.  There are 5 groups of order 8, the other two nonabelian groups being the quaternions and the dihedral group of order 8.  The answer to the problem should be 2 groups.  There is one abelian group of order 8 that is not realized as the group of units of $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: yes, my answers are the same. thank you